# Simplifying Large Bases with large Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I'm told to find:

$105 308^{7125} \pmod {11}$

I'm not exactly sure how to go about calculating this.
I know that I could split the exponent into multiples of it, for instance.

$7125 = 7 * 10 * 10 * 10 * \cdots $ whatever else

As such: $105308^{7(10)(etc..)}$

But even then the base number is too big to be multiplied to get an actual answer on a calculator, any ideas?

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $105308\equiv 5\pmod{11}$ and since $11$ is a prime, you can reduce the exponent using Fermat's Little Theorem. We'll get,

$$105308^{7125}\equiv 5^5\equiv 25^2\times 5\equiv 3^2\times 5\equiv 45\equiv 1\pmod{11}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that $105308 \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$.

So, $$105308^{7125} \equiv 5^{7125} \pmod {11}$$ By [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $5^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$.

We have that $$5^{7125} \equiv 5^{5} \equiv 125 \times 25 \equiv 4 \times 3 \equiv 1  \pmod {11}$$

Comment: How would one know that 105308 is congruent to 5(mod 11)

Comment: @TTEd $105308=105 \times 10^3+105+203=105 \times (10^3+1) +203$. But it is easy to see $203=18 \times 11+5$. And $10^3+1=(10+1)(10^2-10+1) \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$. Thus we have $105308 \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$.

Comment: @TTEd Do you understand?

Comment: So the final answer is 5^5 mod 11 which = 1? i'm just not sure how to write out/ understand the final answer

Comment: Yes, the final answer is $5^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$.

Comment: So out of curiosity, would 7^10505 (mod 11) . also be = 1, since 7 is congruent to 6 mod 11?